# How do the Fourier Transform of sampling and the Frequency-domain convolution match?

Tags: fourier-analysis, continuity, sampling

The Fourier Transform(FT) is 
$X(\upsilon) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-2{\pi}i{\upsilon}t}dt$.

The impulse train is 
$\delta_1(x)=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-k)$, and its FT is $\delta_1(\upsilon)$.

Sample $x(t)$ with $\delta_1(x)$, then the FT of
$ x(t)\delta_1(x) $ is $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x(k)e^{-2\pi i\upsilon k}$.

On the other hand, the FT of
$ x(t)\delta_1(x) $ is $X(\upsilon)\star\delta_1(\upsilon) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X(\upsilon-k)$.

So $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x(k)e^{-2\pi i\upsilon k} = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X(\upsilon-k)$.

Now whether $x(t)$ is compactly supported on $[0, N]$ or $[0, N)$, $X(\upsilon)$ seems to be be the same, so does the right part $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X(\upsilon-k)$, but the left part $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x(k)e^{-2\pi i\upsilon k}$ differs. One is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}x(k)e^{-2\pi i\upsilon k}$, and the other is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1}x(k)e^{-2\pi i\upsilon k}$.

So what is the condition for $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x(k)e^{-2\pi i\upsilon k} = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}X(\upsilon-k)$ ?

I think it is right if $x(t)$ is continuous, but don't know why. And which book is recommended for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) and related to Fourier series and the sampling theorem. It is sufficient if both the function and its Fourier transform fall faster than quadratically. If I remember correctly (yes, see wikipedia), the boundedness of

$$(1+|t|)^{1+\varepsilon}x(t)\text{ and }(1+|v|)^{1+\varepsilon}\,|X(v)|$$

for some $\varepsilon>0$ is a rather minimal sufficient condition.

All this is mathematically expanded on nicely in [Benedetto/Zimmermann 1997](https://www.uni-hohenheim.de/~gzim/Publications/sm.html), also to recommend as nice reading is [Higgins: Five stories... 1985](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183552334).